# r functions calling lm with subsets

Tags: r, function, subset, lm

I was working on some code and I noticed something peculiar.
When I run LM on a subset of some panel data I have it works fine, something like this:

```
library('plm')
data(Cigar)
lm(log(price) ~ log(pop) + log(ndi), data=Cigar, subset=Cigar$state==1)

Call:
lm(formula = log(price) ~ log(pop) + log(ndi), data = Cigar, 
subset = Cigar$state == 1)


Coefficients:
(Intercept)     log(pop)     log(ndi)  
  -26.4919       3.2749       0.4265
```

but when I try to wrap this in a function I get:

```
myfunction <- function(formula, data, subset){
  return(lm(formula, data, subset))
}

myfunction(formula = log(price) ~ log(pop) + log(ndi), data = Cigar, subset = Cigar$state==1)

Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

I really don't understand what's going on here, but it's breaking some other code I've written so I would like to know.

Comment: just a guess, try `subset = state==1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be with the subset.  I get the same error from your function when I change to `subset = (state == 1)`.  The arguments to your function aren't being passed and evaluated correctly.

I think you'd be better off using `do.call`

```
myfunction <- function(formula, data, subset) {
    do.call("lm", as.list(match.call()[-1]))
}

myfunction(log(price) ~ log(pop) + log(ndi), Cigar, state == 1)    
# Call:
# lm(formula = log(price) ~ log(pop) + log(ndi), data = Cigar, 
#     subset = state == 1)
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)     log(pop)     log(ndi)  
#    -26.4919       3.2749       0.4265
```

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely running into problems with Non-Standard evaluation (the `lm` function uses non-standard evaluation).  Functions that use non-standard evaluation are convenient at the command line, but can cause problems when called from within other functions.

Some additional reading on the topic include [Standard Nonstandard Evaluation Rules](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf) and [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) in Advanced R