# Non-standard evaluation in a user-defined function with lapply or with in R

Tags: r, function, lapply, evaluation, do.call

I wrote a wrapper around `ftable` because I need to compute flat tables with frequency and percentage for many variables. As `ftable` method for class "formula" uses non-standard evaluation, the wrapper relies on `do.call` and `match.call` to allow the use of the `subset` argument of `ftable` (more details in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754330)).

```
mytable <- function(...) {
    do.call(what = ftable,
            args = as.list(x = match.call()[-1]))
    # etc
}
```

However, I cannot use this wrapper with `lapply` nor `with`:

```
# example 1: error with "lapply"
lapply(X = warpbreaks[c("breaks",
                        "wool",
                        "tension")],
       FUN = mytable,
       row.vars = 1)

Error in (function (x, ...)  : object 'X' not found

# example 2: error with "with"
with(data = warpbreaks[warpbreaks$tension == "L", ],
     expr = mytable(wool))

Error in (function (x, ...)  : object 'wool' not found
```

These errors seem to be due to `match.call` not being evaluated in the right environment.

As this question is closely linked to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754330), here is a sum up of my problems:

- The wrapper with `do.call` and `match.call` cannot be used with `lapply` or `with`.
- The wrapper without `do.call` and `match.call` cannot use the `subset` argument of `ftable`.

And a sum up of my questions:

- How can I write a wrapper which allows both to use the `subset` argument of `ftable` and to be used with `lapply` and `with`? I have ideas to avoid the use of `lapply` and `with`, but I am looking to understand and correct these errors to improve my knowledge of R.
- Is the error with `lapply` related to the following note from `?lapply`?

  > For historical reasons, the calls created by lapply are unevaluated,
  >   and code has been written (e.g., bquote) that relies on this. This
  >   means that the recorded call is always of the form FUN(X[[i]], ...),
  >   with i replaced by the current (integer or double) index. This is not
  >   normally a problem, but it can be if FUN uses sys.call or match.call
  >   or if it is a primitive function that makes use of the call. This
  >   means that it is often safer to call primitive functions with a
  >   wrapper, so that e.g. lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x)) is
  >   required to ensure that method dispatch for is.numeric occurs
  >   correctly.

Comment: @RLave Thank you for your comment. I have heavely edited my question. Hope it helps !

Comment: @Swolf Thank you, but I get the same error. Not you ?

Comment: Am I correct that you're trying to pass all the arguments passed to `mytable` into `ftable`?

Comment: @divibisan Yes, exactly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/42), the wrapper became:

```
# function 1
mytable <- function(...) {
    do.call(what = ftable,
            args = as.list(x = match.call()[-1]),
            envir = parent.frame())
    # etc
}
```

Or:

```
# function 2
mytable <- function(...) {
    mc <- match.call()
    mc[[1]] <- quote(expr = ftable)
    eval.parent(expr = mc)
    # etc
}
```

I can now use the `subset` argument of `ftable`, and use the wrapper in `lapply`:

```
lapply(X = warpbreaks[c("wool",
                        "tension")],
       FUN = function(x) mytable(formula = x ~ breaks,
                                 data = warpbreaks,
                                 subset = breaks < 15))
```

However I do not understand why I have to supply `envir = parent.frame()` to `do.call` as it is a default argument.

More importantly, these methods do not resolve another issue: [I can not use the `subset` argument of `ftable` with mapply](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56817969/11148823).

Comment: I've posted an answer that hopefully explains what's happening here in more depth, though you basically figured it out already yourself. For your "bonus questions", you should ask new questions for them – the StackOverflow format is made for 1 question per question

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `match.call` with `lapply` is that `match.call` returns the *literal* call that passed into it, without any interpretation. To see what's going on, let's make a simpler function which shows exactly how your function is interpreting the arguments passed into it:

```
match_call_fun <- function(...) {
    call = as.list(match.call()[-1])
    print(call)
}
```

When we call it directly, `match.call` correctly gets the arguments and puts them in a list that we can use with `do.call`:

```
match_call_fun(iris['Species'], 9)

[[1]]
iris["Species"]

[[2]]
[1] 9
```

But watch what happens when we use `lapply` (I've only included the output of the internal `print` statement):

```
lapply('Species', function(x) match_call_fun(iris[x], 9))

[[1]]
iris[x]

[[2]]
[1] 9
```

Since `match.call` gets the *literal* arguments passed to it, it receives `iris[x]`, not the properly interpreted `iris['Species']` that we want. When we pass those arguments into `ftable` with `do.call`, it looks for an object `x` in the current environment, and then returns an error when it can't find it. We need to interpret

As you've seen, adding `envir = parent.frame()` fixes the problem. This is because, adding that argument tells `do.call` to evaluate `iris[x]` in the parent frame, which is the anonymous function in `lapply` where `x` has it's proper meaning. To see this in action, let's make another simple function that uses `do.call` to print `ls` from 3 different environmental levels:

```
z <- function(...) {
    print(do.call(ls, list()))
    print(do.call(ls, list(), envir = parent.frame()))
    print(do.call(ls, list(), envir = parent.frame(2)))
}
```

When we call `z()` from the global environment, we see the empty environment inside the function, then the Global Environment:

```
z()

character(0)                                  # Interior function environment
[1] "match_call_fun" "y"              "z"     # GlobalEnv
[1] "match_call_fun" "y"              "z"     # GlobalEnv
```

But when we call from within `lapply`, we see that one level of `parent.frame` up is the anonymous function in `lapply`:

```
lapply(1, z)

character(0)                                  # Interior function environment
[1] "FUN" "i"   "X"                           # lapply
[1] "match_call_fun" "y"              "z"     # GlobalEnv
```

So, by adding `envir = parent.frame()`, `do.call` knows to evaluate `iris[x]` in the `lapply` environment where it knows that `x` is actually `'Species'`, and it evaluates correctly.

```
mytable_envir <- function(...) {
    tab <- do.call(what = ftable,
                   args = as.list(match.call()[-1]),
                   envir = parent.frame())
    prop <- prop.table(x = tab,
                       margin = 2) * 100
    bind <- cbind(as.matrix(x = tab),
                  as.matrix(x = prop))
    margin <- addmargins(A = bind,
                         margin = 1)
    round(x = margin,
          digits = 1)
}



# This works!
lapply(X = c("breaks","wool","tension"),
       FUN = function(x) mytable_envir(warpbreaks[x],row.vars = 1))
```

---

As for why adding `envir = parent.frame()` makes a difference since that appears to be the default option. I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that when the default argument is used, `parent.frame` is evaluated *inside* the `do.call` function, returning the environment in which `do.call` is run. What we're doing, however, is calling `parent.frame` *outside* `do.call`, which means it returns one level higher than the default version.

Here's a test function that takes `parent.frame()` as a default value:

```
fun <- function(y=parent.frame()) {
    print(y)
    print(parent.frame())
    print(parent.frame(2))
    print(parent.frame(3))
}
```

Now look at what happens when we call it from within `lapply` both with and without passing in `parent.frame()` as an argument:

```
lapply(1, function(y) fun())
<environment: 0x12c5bc1b0>     # y argument
<environment: 0x12c5bc1b0>     # parent.frame called inside
<environment: 0x12c5bc760>     # 1 level up = lapply
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>     # 2 levels up = globalEnv

lapply(1, function(y) fun(y = parent.frame()))
<environment: 0x104931358>     # y argument
<environment: 0x104930da8>     # parent.frame called inside
<environment: 0x104931358>     # 1 level up = lapply
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>     # 2 levels up = globalEnv
```

In the first example, the value of `y` is the same as what you get when you call `parent.frame()` inside the function. In the second example, the value of `y` is the same as the environment one level up (inside `lapply`). So, while they look the same, they're actually doing different things: in the first example, `parent.frame` is being evaluated inside the function when it sees that there is no `y=` argument, in the second, `parent.frame` is evaluated in the `lapply` anonymous function *first*, before calling `fun`, and then is passed into it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. It helps me to understand more in depth. However, about why `parent.frame()` is needed although it is the default argument, I don't see why the behavior of the default argument would be different as if the same argument were specified manually...

Comment: Thank you very much again, for your edit this time ! I now understand why adding `envir = parent.frame()` makes a difference even if it is `do.call` default argument. You deserve more than +1 for the help you provided ! NB: `with(data = warpbreaks, expr = z())`, `with(warpbreaks, fun())` and `with(warpbreaks, fun(y = parent.frame()))` also demonstrate that the problem was the same with `with`.

Comment: No problem, it was fun to figure out! I tend to avoid environments wherever possible in my own work since I don't fully understand them. So it's good for me to take the time to dig into how they actually work

Comment: I finally realize the wrapper fails with `mapply` although it works with `lapply`. Can you please have a look to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56817969/11148823 ?

Comment: For the record, about why adding `envir = parent.frame()` makes a difference even if it is do.call default argument: "One of the most important things to know about the evaluation of arguments to a function is that supplied arguments and default arguments are treated differently. The supplied arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function. The default arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function." (from https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to pass all the arguments passed to ftable u do not need the do.call().

```
mytable <- function(...) {
  tab <- ftable(...)
  prop <- prop.table(x = tab,
                     margin = 2) * 100
  bind <- cbind(as.matrix(x = tab),
                as.matrix(x = prop))
  margin <- addmargins(A = bind,
                       margin = 1)
  return(round(x = margin,
               digits = 1))
}
```

The following lapply creates a table for every Variable separatly i don't know if that is what you want.

```
lapply(X = c("breaks",
             "wool",
             "tension"),
       FUN = function(x) mytable(warpbreaks[x],
                                 row.vars = 1))
```

If you want all 3 variables in 1 table

```
warpbreaks$newVar <- LETTERS[3:4]

lapply(X = cbind("c(\"breaks\", \"wool\", \"tension\")",
             "c(\"newVar\", \"tension\",\"wool\")"),
       FUN = function(X)
        eval(parse(text=paste("mytable(warpbreaks[,",X,"],
                                 row.vars = 1)")))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as explained in my question, I need `do.call` to use the subset argument of `ftable` method for class "formula" because it uses non-standard evaluation (more details on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754330/write-a-wrapper-around-a-function-relying-on-non-standard-evaluation-in-r)).