# Non-standard evaluation of subset argument with mapply in R

Tags: r, scope, subset, evaluation, mapply

I can not use the `subset` argument of `xtabs` or `aggregate` (or any function I tested, including `ftable` and `lm`) with `mapply`. The following calls fail with the `subset` argument, but they work without:

```
mapply(FUN = xtabs,
       formula = list(~ wool,
                      ~ wool + tension),
       subset = list(breaks < 15,
                     breaks < 20),
       MoreArgs = list(data = warpbreaks))

# Error in mapply(FUN = xtabs, formula = list(~wool, ~wool + tension), subset = list(breaks <  : 
#   object 'breaks' not found
# 
# expected result 1/2:
# wool
# A B 
# 2 2
# 
# expected result 2/2:
#     tension
# wool L M H
#    A 0 4 3
#    B 2 2 5

mapply(FUN = aggregate,
       formula = list(breaks ~ wool,
                      breaks ~ wool + tension),
       subset = list(breaks < 15,
                     breaks < 20),
       MoreArgs = list(data = warpbreaks,
                       FUN = length))

# Error in mapply(FUN = aggregate, formula = list(breaks ~ wool, breaks ~  : 
#   object 'breaks' not found
# 
# expected result 1/2:
#   wool breaks
# 1    A      2
# 2    B      2
# 
# expected result 2/2:
#   wool tension breaks
# 1    B       L      2
# 2    A       M      4
# 3    B       M      2
# 4    A       H      3
# 5    B       H      5
```

The errors seem to be due to `subset` arguments not being evaluated in the right environment. I know I can subset in the `data` argument with `data = warpbreaks[warpbreaks$breaks < 20, ]` as a workaround, but I am looking to improve my knowledge of R.

My questions are:

- How can I use `subset` arguments with `mapply`? I tried with `match.call` and `eval.parent`, but without success so far (more details in my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828617/11148823)).
- Why is the `formula` argument evaluated in `data = warpbreaks`, but
  the `subset` argument is not?

Comment: For the record, this is not restricted to `mapply` but also apply to e.g. `lapply`: (i) this works: `lapply(X = list(warpbreaks, warpbreaks), FUN = xtabs, formula = ~ wool)`; but (ii) this fails: `lapply(X = list(warpbreaks, warpbreaks), FUN = xtabs, formula = ~ wool, subset = breaks < 15)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that when you create a list to pass as an argument to a function, it is evaluated at the point of creation. The error you are getting is because R tries to create the list you want to pass in the calling environment.

To see this more clearly, suppose you try creating the arguments you want to pass ahead of calling `mapply`:

```r
f_list <- list(~ wool, ~ wool + tension)
d_list <- list(data = warpbreaks)
mapply(FUN = xtabs, formula = f_list, MoreArgs = d_list)
#> [[1]]
#> wool
#>  A  B 
#> 27 27 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 9 9 9
#>    B 9 9 9
```

There is no problem with creating a list of formulas, because these are not evaluated until needed, and of course `warpbreaks` is accessible from the global environment, hence this call to `mapply` works.

Of course, if you try to create the following list ahead of the `mapply` call:

```
subset_list <- list(breaks < 15, breaks < 20)
```

Then R will tell you that `breaks` isn't found.

However, if you create the list with `warpbreaks` in the search path, then you won't have a problem:

```r
subset_list <- with(warpbreaks, list(breaks < 15, breaks < 20))
subset_list
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [14]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [27] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [40] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [53] FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [14]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [27] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [40]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [53]  TRUE FALSE
```

so you would think that we could just pass this to `mapply` and everything would be fine, but now we get a new error:

```r
mapply(FUN = xtabs, formula = f_list, subset = subset_list, MoreArgs = d_list)
#> Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : object 'dots' not found
```

So why are we getting this?

The problem lies in any functions passed to `mapply` that call `eval`, or that themselves call a function that uses `eval`.

If you look at the source code for `mapply` you will see that it takes the extra arguments you have passed and puts them in a list called `dots`, which it will then pass to an internal `mapply` call:

```r
mapply
#> function (FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
#> {
#>     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#>     dots <- list(...)
#>     answer <- .Internal(mapply(FUN, dots, MoreArgs))
#> ...
```

If your `FUN` itself calls another function that calls `eval` on any of its arguments, it will therefore try to `eval` the object `dots`, which won't exist in the environment in which the `eval` is called. This is easy to see by doing an `mapply` on a `match.call` wrapper:

```
mapply(function(x) match.call(), x = list(1))
[[1]]
(function(x) match.call())(x = dots[[1L]][[1L]])
```

So a minimal reproducible example of our error is

```
mapply(function(x) eval(substitute(x)), x = list(1))
#> Error in eval(substitute(x)) : object 'dots' not found
```

---

So what's the solution? It seems like you have already hit on a perfectly good one, that is, manually subsetting the data frame you wish to pass. Others may suggest that you explore `purrr::map` to get a more elegant solution.

However, it *is* possible to get `mapply` to do what you want, and the secret is just to modify `FUN` to turn it into an anonymous wrapper of `xtabs` that subsets on the fly:

```r
mapply(FUN = function(formula, subset, data) xtabs(formula, data[subset,]), 
       formula = list(~ wool, ~ wool + tension),
       subset = with(warpbreaks, list(breaks < 15, breaks < 20)),
       MoreArgs = list(data = warpbreaks))
#> [[1]]
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5
```

Comment: What a day! after your excellent answer this morning, here is another one. Thank you for your pedagogy, I am glad I learned more about R. I have already upvoted your answer, but I wait until the deadline to validate it and award the bounty to keep the question attractive.

Comment: The fact `mapply(FUN = xtabs, formula = f_list, subset = subset_list, MoreArgs = d_list)` doesn't work is a bug in my opinion, the doc of `xtabs` and `aggregate` say `subset` is a "an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be used", and this is what you feed here. The doc actually doesn't even mention that `subset` will be evaluated in the context of the data

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes, this seems to be a product of the way that `xtabs` calls `model.frame`. Instead of manually listing all the arguments that are to be passed from the `xtabs` call, it does a `match.call` and changes the function in the call object to `model.frame` while preserving all the arguments. Clever, but lazy, and ultimately buggy: since `model.frame` uses `eval`, this approach doesn't work if called through `mapply` for the reasons outlined above.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper and Allan Cameron: Thank you for these additional details, I had not come to the conclusion by myself that it was a bug. Do you intend to report it? If not, I can do it, but I might be a bit short technically to provide enough useful information...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it'll be accepted as a bug though in my opinion it is (to be sure we're talking about Allan's proposal here, what you tried in your question is expected to fail). I'll report it to R devel.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thank you for your report! For the record, the thread on R devel is here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-May/079421.html

Comment: For information, this behavior is not a bug and is documented according to Charles Berry: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-May/079425.html

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper eipi10 I accepted and awarded Allan Cameron's answer, because he was the first to answer, providing a detailed answer that specifically answered my question using base R. I hope you don't mind! Anyway, your answers really helped too!

Comment: It's a great answer, and I have enough points :). Good question too.

Answer (score 4):

@AllanCameron alluded to the possibility of a `purrr::map` solution. Here are a few options:

1. Since we know we want to subset by the `breaks` column, we only need to provide the cutoff values and therefore don't have to worry about delaying evaluation of an expression. Here and in the other examples, we name the elements of the breaks list so that the output will also have names telling us what `breaks` cutoff value was used. Also, in all examples we take advantage of the `dplyr::filter` function to filter the data in the `data` argument, rather than the `subset` argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2(list(breaks.lt.15=15,
          breaks.lt.20=20),
     list(~ wool,
          ~ wool + tension),
     ~ xtabs(.y, data=filter(warpbreaks, breaks < .x))
)
#> $breaks.lt.15
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> $breaks.lt.20
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5
```

2. Similar to above, but we supply the whole filter expression and wrap the filter expressions in `quos` to delay evaluation. `!!.x` evaluates the expressions at the point where we filter the `warpbreaks` data frame inside `xtabs`.

```
map2(quos(breaks.lt.15=breaks < 15,
          breaks.lt.20=breaks < 20),
     list(~ wool,
          ~ wool + tension),
     ~ xtabs(.y, data=filter(warpbreaks, !!.x))
)
#> $breaks.lt.15
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> $breaks.lt.20
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5
```

3. In case you want all combinations of filters and xtabs formulas, you can use the `crossing` function to generate the combinations and then pass that to `pmap` ("parallel map"), which can take any number of arguments, all contained in a single list. In this case we use `rlang::exprs` instead of `quos` to delay evaluation. `rlang::exprs` would also have worked above, but `quos` doesn't work here. I'm not sure I really understand why, but it has to do with capturing both the expression and its environment (`quos`) vs. capturing just the expression (`exprs`), as discussed [here](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html).

```
# map over all four combinations of breaks and xtabs formulas
crossing(
  rlang::exprs(breaks.lt.15=breaks < 15,
               breaks.lt.20=breaks < 20),
  list(~ wool,
       ~ wool + tension)
) %>% 
  pmap(~ xtabs(.y, data=filter(warpbreaks, !!.x)))
#> $breaks.lt.15
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> $breaks.lt.15
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 1 1
#>    B 1 0 1
#> 
#> $breaks.lt.20
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 7 9 
#> 
#> $breaks.lt.20
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5
```

You could also go with tidyverse functions for the summary instead of `xtabs` and return a data frame. For example:

```r
map2_df(c(15,20),
        list("wool",
             c("wool", "tension")),
        ~ warpbreaks %>% 
            filter(breaks < .x) %>% 
            group_by_at(.y) %>% 
            tally() %>% 
            bind_cols(max.breaks=.x - 1)
) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, ~replace_na(fct_expand(., "All"), "All")) %>% 
  select(is.factor, everything())   # Using select this way requires development version of dplyr, soon to be released on CRAN as version 1.0.0
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   wool  tension     n max.breaks
#>   <fct> <fct>   <int>      <dbl>
#> 1 A     All         2         14
#> 2 B     All         2         14
#> 3 A     M           4         19
#> 4 A     H           3         19
#> 5 B     L           2         19
#> 6 B     M           2         19
#> 7 B     H           5         19
```

If you wanted to include marginal counts, you could do:

```r
crossing(
  c(Inf,15,20),
  list(NULL, "wool", "tension", c("wool", "tension"))
) %>% 
  pmap_df(
    ~ warpbreaks %>% 
        filter(breaks < .x) %>% 
        group_by_at(.y) %>% 
        tally() %>% 
        bind_cols(max.breaks=.x - 1)
  ) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, ~replace_na(fct_expand(., "All"), "All")) %>% 
  select(is.factor, everything()) 

#>    wool tension  n max.breaks
#> 1   All     All  4         14
#> 2     A     All  2         14
#> 3     B     All  2         14
#> 4   All       L  1         14
#> 5   All       M  1         14
#> 6   All       H  2         14
#> 7     A       M  1         14
#> 8     A       H  1         14
#> 9     B       L  1         14
#> 10    B       H  1         14
#> 11  All     All 16         19
#> 12    A     All  7         19
#> 13    B     All  9         19
#> 14  All       L  2         19
#> 15  All       M  6         19
#> 16  All       H  8         19
#> 17    A       M  4         19
#> 18    A       H  3         19
#> 19    B       L  2         19
#> 20    B       M  2         19
#> 21    B       H  5         19
#> 22  All     All 54        Inf
#> 23    A     All 27        Inf
#> 24    B     All 27        Inf
#> 25  All       L 18        Inf
#> 26  All       M 18        Inf
#> 27  All       H 18        Inf
#> 28    A       L  9        Inf
#> 29    A       M  9        Inf
#> 30    A       H  9        Inf
#> 31    B       L  9        Inf
#> 32    B       M  9        Inf
#> 33    B       H  9        Inf
```

And if we add a `pivot_wider` onto the end of the previous chain, we can get:

```
pivot_wider(names_from=max.breaks, values_from=n, 
            names_prefix="breaks<=", values_fill=list(n=0))
```

> ```
>    wool  tension `breaks<=14` `breaks<=19` `breaks<=Inf`
>  1 All   All                4           16            54
>  2 A     All                2            7            27
>  3 B     All                2            9            27
>  4 All   L                  1            2            18
>  5 All   M                  1            6            18
>  6 All   H                  2            8            18
>  7 A     M                  1            4             9
>  8 A     H                  1            3             9
>  9 B     L                  1            2             9
> 10 B     H                  1            5             9
> 11 B     M                  0            2             9
> 12 A     L                  0            0             9
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer!

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue of NSE. One way is to inject the subset conditions in the call directly so they can be applied in the relevant context (the data, where `breaks` exist).

It can be done by using `alist()` instead of `list()`, to have a list of quoted expressions,
then build the correct call, (using `bquote()` is the easiest way) and evaluate it.

```r
mapply(
  FUN = function(formula, data, subset) 
    eval(bquote(xtabs(formula, data, .(subset)))),
  formula = list(~ wool,
                 ~ wool + tension),
  subset = alist(breaks < 15,
                 breaks < 20),
  MoreArgs = list(data = warpbreaks))
#> [[1]]
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5

mapply(FUN = function(formula, data, FUN, subset)
  eval(bquote(aggregate(formula, data, FUN, subset = .(subset)))),
  formula = list(breaks ~ wool,
                 breaks ~ wool + tension),
  subset = alist(breaks < 15,
                 breaks < 20),
  MoreArgs = list(data = warpbreaks,
                  FUN = length))
#> [[1]]
#>   wool breaks
#> 1    A      2
#> 2    B      2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   wool tension breaks
#> 1    B       L      2
#> 2    A       M      4
#> 3    B       M      2
#> 4    A       H      3
#> 5    B       H      5
```

You don't really need  `MoreArgs` anymore as you can use the arguments directly in the call, so you might want to simplify it as follows :

```
mapply(
  FUN = function(formula, subset) 
    eval(bquote(xtabs(formula, warpbreaks, subset = .(subset)))),
  formula = list(~ wool,
                 ~ wool + tension),
  subset = alist(breaks < 15,
                 breaks < 20))
#> [[1]]
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5

mapply(FUN = function(formula, subset)
  eval(bquote(aggregate(formula, warpbreaks, length, subset = .(subset)))),
  formula = list(breaks ~ wool,
                 breaks ~ wool + tension),
  subset = alist(breaks < 15,
                 breaks < 20))
#> [[1]]
#>   wool breaks
#> 1    A      2
#> 2    B      2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   wool tension breaks
#> 1    B       L      2
#> 2    A       M      4
#> 3    B       M      2
#> 4    A       H      3
#> 5    B       H      5
```

You could also avoid the call manipulation and the adhoc `FUN` argument by building datasets to loop on using lapply :

```r
mapply(
  FUN =  xtabs,
  formula = list(~ wool,
                 ~ wool + tension),
  data =  lapply(c(15, 20), function(x) subset(warpbreaks, breaks < x)))
#> [[1]]
#> wool
#> A B 
#> 2 2 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     tension
#> wool L M H
#>    A 0 4 3
#>    B 2 2 5

mapply(
  FUN =  aggregate,
  formula = list(breaks ~ wool,
                 breaks ~ wool + tension),
  data =  lapply(c(15, 20), function(x) subset(warpbreaks, breaks < x)),
  MoreArgs = list(FUN = length))
#> [[1]]
#>   wool breaks
#> 1    A      2
#> 2    B      2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   wool tension breaks
#> 1    B       L      2
#> 2    A       M      4
#> 3    B       M      2
#> 4    A       H      3
#> 5    B       H      5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I am not sure I understood correctly. Can you confirm that `.()` avoids `bquote` to "requote" the subset argument because it was already quoted from `alist`? P.S. A recommended read for readers needing background informations like me: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: I think you got it about right. In other words what `.()` does inside of `bquote()` (and only there) is evaluate its input and insert the result into the quoted expression. The following : `x <- 1; y <- 2; z <- quote(ZZZ); bquote(x + .(y) + .(z)) `, will return `quote(x + 2 + ZZZ)`. Anything that can be done with `bquote()` can be done with `substitute()`, but `bquote()` is more compact when it can be used.

Comment: you can try to replace `eval(bquote(xtabs(formula, data, .(subset))))` by `eval(print(bquote(xtabs(formula, data, .(subset)))))`, it will print the calls before evaluation